# greek text in LaTeX (along with latin text)

Tags: greek

I want to write greek and latin.
As a miniumum example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\title{Το θεώρημα του \textlatin{Lami}\footnote{\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernard_Lamy}}}
\author{Δημήτριος Σ. Αναγνώστου}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

However, the link in the footnote appears with greek characters.
[image]

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you have to insert also the url inside `\textlatin{}`

Comment: I add it and it doesn't work either. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Did you used it twice? I mean, `\url{\textlatin{}}` or opposite, `\textlatin{\url{}}`.

Comment: Sorry! You are right! I was doing it with the reverse order. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most convenient way is to use `polyglossia` package together with `unicode-math` package, and to compile your document using `xelatex` or `lualatex` engine, respectively. However, you must ensure that you have installed in your system a font that supports greek characters. Here is a MWE:

```
     \documentclass[11pt]{article}

    \usepackage{unicode-math} % loads fontspec package
    \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
    \setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFS Artemisia} % alternative times-font is xits

    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{english}
    \setotherlanguage[variant=modern]{greek} 

    \usepackage{hyperref}

    \setlength{\textheight}{8cm} % just for this example

    \title{Το θεώρημα του Lami \footnote{\protect\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernard_Lamy}}}
    \author{Δημήτριος Σ. Αναγνώστου}

    \begin{document}

 \maketitle

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

It makes sense to define `\url` to ensure `\latintext`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareUrlCommand\url{\def\UrlFont{\latintext\ttfamily}}

\setlength{\textheight}{8cm} % just for this example

\begin{document}

\title{Το θεώρημα του \textlatin{Lamy}\footnote{\protect\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernard_Lamy}}}
\author{Δημήτριος Σ. Αναγνώστου}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Don't forget `\protect` when `\url` is in a footnote.

[image]